# Findings letters that match in every sublist

Tags: python, for-loop, collections, nested-loops, nested-lists

```
candidates = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

If a candidate appears in every sublist at least once they must be returned

```
listOfData = [['B','C','B','A'], #D is no longer a candidate
              ['B', 'C', 'B', 'D'], #A is no loner a candidate
              ['A','D','C','B'], # B and C are still candidates
              ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A']] # B and C are solid matches!
```

In this case the matches are `[B,C]`

I'm having trouble keeping track of the `candidate` that appears in every `sublist` at least once.

```
matches =[]           
def lettersThatMatchInEverySublist():
    i=0
    for candidate in candidates:
        for sublist in listOfData:
            for char in sublist:
                pass
        if char == candidate:
            matches.append(candidate)

    return matches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way - with sets

```
>>> valid_vals = tuple(set(row) for row in listOfData)
>>> candidates = set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> for validator in valid_vals:
    candidates &= validator


>>> candidates
set(['C', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few guiding measures that can get you started, but beyond this, you will need to restate your problem more clearly.

Try using `itertools` for your `listOfOptions`:

```
import itertools

options = itertools.product('ACTG', repeat=3)  # This finds all the combinations of A, C, T, and G.
listOfOptions = [''.join(option) for option in options]  # This uses list comprehension to prepare your options.
```

Clean up the `findKmersSet` function:

```
def findKmersSet(k, dataset):
    dataset = dataset.splitlines()
    kmers = []
    for line in dataset:
        line_list = []
        for i in range(len(line)-k+1):
            line_list.append(line[i:i+k])
        kmers.append(line_list)
    return kmers
```